# "Delete Unique Permissions",

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-permissions

is it possible to backup/restore only permissions for an SP2013 site?

Trying to be proactive for our SP2013 on-prem site.

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box. I looked to see if a developer could create an Event Receiver that could do this, but I could not find an event that fires for a list/library item when inheritance is broken.

Answer (score 0):

@MikeSmith has right, it's not supported OOB. You don't need however any event receivers to achieve that. We have a home-made PowerShell + C# -based solution for a similar problem (we aim to document the state of the permission settings on a daily basis, kind of reporting, to be able to confirm / reproduce the settings later). It simply browses the structure of the site structure, looking for the security settings and archives them into CSV-files and / or SQL tables.

Comment: Would you mind sharing this with me at all?

Comment: Sorry I can't / am not allowed to. It's a solution we created for a customer, and it is the property of that customer.

Comment: would you be able to point in the right direction as to how I could accomplish this on my own? Maybe some sites which helped you?